# How do I echo the each posts category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am looking to make wordpress print/echo the category name of a post into it's class. I need this to work on the index page inside the main loop. Here is what I mean:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <article class="<?php ** I NEED THIS CODE ** ?>">
            <div>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail(); } else {} ?>
        </article>

    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Hopefully you understand my poor description of my issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://lorelle.wordpress.com/2007/09/06/using-wordpress-categories-to-style-posts/

Add the following to your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function the_category_unlinked($separator = ' ') {
    $categories = (array) get_the_category();

    $thelist = '';
    foreach($categories as $category) {    // concate
        $thelist .= $separator . $category->category_nicename;
    }

    echo $thelist;
}
```

And the corresponding markup would be:

```
<article class="<?php the_category_unlinked(' '); ?>">
```

Comment: @Aibrean Yes, as shown very clearly in the URL to the article, it was posted on September 6th, 2007. However, the code cited above still works because the functions used here haven't changed. Age of an article should not be of concern unless the functions used have been marked as deprecated or have been dropped from the API.